# how many times is the expression inside switch gets invoked

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

Given a switch statement like this:

```
switch(text.toLowerCase()) {
    case("aaa"):
        doSomething();
        return;
    case("bbb"):
        doSomething();
        return;
    case("ccc"):
        doSomething();
        return;
    default:
        return;
}
```

How many times does the expression inside the switch itself gets invoke?

- Will it call toLowerCase() in every case that it checks (which would mean that it would better to insert this expression to a variable before that switch case and use that variable inside the switch)
- Or will it evaluate the toLowerCase() once and use the final expression's value for all the cases?

Comment: It will throw an error. You should use `break` instead of return

Comment: Once. It's evaluated once and then compared (as with `===`) to each `case` value.

Comment: It will be invoked once only !!!

Comment: @Ayrton that is not at all true.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The expression inside `switch` statement is invoked only one time.

This is one of the usefulness of this statement, comparing to `if`/`else if` statement (where effectively it would be better to first assign the result in a variable).

If you want to be absolutely sure about that, you can test it yourself like that, with your own version of `toLowerCase()` (overriding `String.prototype` for test purposes):

```
var nbTime = 0;
var text = '';

String.prototype.toLowerCaseNbTime = function() {
    console.log(++nbTime)  // -> 1
    return this.toLowerCase();
}

switch(text.toLowerCaseNbTime()) {
    case("aaa"):
        doSomething();
        return;
    case("bbb"):
        doSomething();
        return;
    case("ccc"):
        doSomething();
        return;
    default:
        return;
}
```